# How to replace a three-digit number with zero

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my code. My program constantly return two-digit and three-digit which is wrong. Task saying that the user adds numbers constantly and need to save in List. When the user press zero program stops asking the user for adding numbers and needs to return three-digit numbers and replace them with number zero and need to return how many three-digit numbers he replace with zero. So basically means need to count zero which replace three-digit numbers. Zero doesn't save in List.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Zadatak_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int broj;

            List<int> listaBrojeva = new List<int>();

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unesite neki broj: ");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out broj);

                if (broj > 0)
                {
                    listaBrojeva.Add(broj);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (broj == 0)
                    {
                        listaBrojeva.Remove(broj);
                    }
                }
            } while (broj != 0);
            Console.WriteLine();

            for(int i=0;i<listaBrojeva.Count;i++)
            {
                if((broj < 100) || (broj > -100))
                {
                    listaBrojeva.Remove(i);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", listaBrojeva[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what result you are expecting; but removing an element of `listaBrojeva` then trying to `WriteLine` the same element looks problematic. Try inspecting `listaBrojeva[i]` in the debugger.

Comment: My program needs to return a zero which replaces three-digit numbers and needs to count how many three-digit numbers he replace. So, for example, user add numbers 5, 10, 50, 78, 100, 110, 123, 788. Programm needs to ignore one and two-digit numbers and needs to replace three-digit numbers with zero and need to show how many three-digit numbers he replace.

Comment: `broj` will always be 0 because your `do` loop stops when `broj == 0`.  I think you want to check if the numbers in your list are 3 digits. `if (listaBrojeva[i] >= 100)` and then you can replace the number with 0. `listaBrojeva[i] = 0;`

Comment: No problem, thank you, we all do sometimes mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood following rules:

1. Program will accept many numbers. When user inputs zero, program will no longer accept numbers.
2. Program has a list that will only accept 2 and 3 digit numbers, that is numbers ranging from 10 to 999.
3. All negative numbers and numbers larger than 999 will not be stored in the list.
4. Out of all 2 and 3 digit numbers in the list, display 2 digit numbers as it is and display three digit numbers as 0.
5. At the end of the program, count the number of 3 digit numbers.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Zadatak_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int broj;

            List<int> listaBrojeva = new List<int>();

            //Accept only two digits and three digits positive numbers in the list
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Unesite neki broj: ");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out broj);

                if (broj >= 10 && broj <= 999)
                {
                    listaBrojeva.Add(broj);
                }                
            } while (broj != 0);

            Console.WriteLine();

            int zeroCounter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listaBrojeva.Count; i++)
            {
                int number = listaBrojeva[i];

                if (number >= 100 && number <= 999)
                {
                    ++zeroCounter;
                    Console.Write("0" + "\t");
                }
                else Console.Write(number + "\t");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nNumber of 3 digit numbers which are replaced by zero is " + zeroCounter);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: That's it, thank you

Comment: @The.Strider I am delighted that I was able to understand and help you with your problem.